# Function $f(x)=x^2+1$. Find a function g with $(f∘g)(x)=x+5$ ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Function $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Find a function $g$ with $(f∘g)(x)=x+5$.

My answer was $g(x) = x^{0.5} + 2$ but that's incorrect because you would still have $4x^{0.5}$ remaining that wouldn't fit the equation.

Comment: "Wouldn't fit the equation" why?

Comment: Well it's "left over", since I need f after g to become x + 5, but using my answer it would become x + 5 + 4x^0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat $g(x)$ like a new variable, say $u$. Then you need $u^2+1=f(u)=f(g(x))=x+5$.

So solve for $u$ and get $u^2=x+4$ and so $u=\pm \sqrt{x+4}$ (take the "+" since it's a little simpler).

So $g(x)=\sqrt{x+4}$ should work. Let's double check:

$$f(g(x))=f(\sqrt{x+4})=(\sqrt{x+4})^2+1 = x+4+1=x+5$$

Answer (score 3):

You have $f(x)=x^2+1$ and you're looking for a $g(x)$ so that $(f \circ g )(x)=x+5.$

So, you solve the following equation for $g(x)$:

$(f \circ g )(x)=f(g(x))=g(x)^2+1=x+5$

so then $g(x)^2=x+4$

therefore either $g(x)=\sqrt{x+4}$ or $g(x)=-\sqrt{x+4}$ will work.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that it will be something like $g(x)=(x+a)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (you'll fit $a$ in the future). Then:

$$f \circ g (x) = f(g(x))=((x+a)^\frac{1}{2})^2+1=x+a+1=x+5$$

So $a+1=5$ and finally $a=4$.

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding an inverse of $f$, in this case $\sqrt{x-1}$ and applying that to the second row. Be vary of the domain restrictions when finding an inverse.